# Fill divs with strings from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, text, random

I want to have divs fill with text stored in a jquery array randomly.
My html looks like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

In my jQuery I have an array that looks like

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]
```

Each cell should be filled with a fruit randomly but I am stuck with iterating over the correctly and picking random values for each div with the class cell. This code obviously does not work:

```
$.each(fruits), function(fruit) {
    var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)];
    $('.row .cell').text(fruit);
}
```

How can I make the random guess happen exactly 5 times and fill the divs correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$('.cell').each(function(){
   $(this).text(fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)])
})
```

Comment: You can also use `index` of `each()`

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```js
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];
$('.cell').each(function(index) {
  $(this).text(fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You needed to iterate on `.cell` elements instead of `fruits` array. Hope this helps.

Comment: ha! @DGS beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

This function will generate the values between the min and max length of array so that you will get appropriate value.

```
$('.cell').each(function(){
   $(this).text(fruits[getRandomInt(0, fruits.length)]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.row .cell').text(fruit)` will change text for every `".cell"`
Here's a quick correction:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]; 

$.each(fruits, function(i, fruit) {
 var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)];
 $('.cell').eq(i).text(fruit);
});
```